# Question 2 in Exercises section 5.8 in the book of Brian Hall's Lie groups,... : an elementary introduction.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\pi$ be an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$ and let $\pi^*$ be the dual representation of $\pi$ defined by $\pi^*(X) = - \pi(X)^T$, where $T$ stands for transpose.
Show that if $\pi$ has highest weight $(m_1,m_2)$ then $\pi^*$ has highest weight $(m_2,m_1)$.

As a hint I am asked to establish this first for $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

From reading the text I am a bit puzzled about to show this.
By definition 5.8 on page 132:
Let $\alpha_1= (2,-1) , \alpha_2 = (-1,2)$ , let $\mu_1 ,\mu_2$ be two weights; $\mu_1$ is higher than $\mu_2$ if $\mu_1-\mu_2 = a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2$ for $a,b \ge 0$; a weight is said to be a highest weight if it's higher than all weights $\mu$ of $\pi$ where $\pi$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$.

Iv'e seen before that the weights of $\pi^*$ are the negatives of weights of $\pi$, how to use this here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me here? also hints are welcomed.